# Is $(\sqrt{n})!=Θ(\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}})$?

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to express $(\sqrt{n})!$ in terms of $Θ()$ notation.

My approach is the following:

$$(\sqrt{n})!=f(n)\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\log(\sqrt{n})!=\log(f(n))$$

Now from Stirling's approximation we get: $$Θ(\sqrt{n}\log(\sqrt{n})=\log(f(n))\Leftrightarrow$$
$$f(n)=Θ(\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}})$$

So, $$(\sqrt{n})!=Θ(\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}})$$

Is this approach correct? I am a bit confused since I used $\log$ equality to prove this and in some cases this doesn't work correctly.

For example, if we get $n!$ and $n^{n}$ we observe that $Θ(\log(n!))=Θ(\log(n^{n})$ .

However we know that $n!=o(n^{n})$ (which means that $n!<n^{n}$ asymptotically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stirling's approximation states that
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n = \Theta(\sqrt{n} (n/e)^n).
$$
Therefore $\sqrt{n}! = \Theta(n^{1/4} (\sqrt{n}/e)^{\sqrt{n}})$. In particular, $\sqrt{n}! = o(\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}})$.

Note also that if all you want is to express $\sqrt{n}!$ in big Theta notation, you can just write $\sqrt{n}! = \Theta(\sqrt{n}!)$.

If $\log f(n) = \Theta(\log g(n))$ then it doesn't follow that $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$. For example, $\log (a^n) = \Theta(\log (b^n))$ for all $a,b > 1$, but $a^n$ is not $\Theta(b^n)$ (unless $a = b$).

Comment: So, If I get it right, it's wrong to use $\log$ equality to express the big Thera notation and using Stirling's approximation I end up with: $\sqrt{n}! = \Theta(n^{1/4} (\sqrt{n}/e)^{\sqrt{n}})$ (which is a different result) ??

Comment: Right, this is an example for why your kind of reasoning is invalid.

Comment: Yeah I see. And that's why if we have $n!$ and $n^{n}$ and we want to compare them asymptotically then getting $Θ(\log(n!))=Θ(\log(n^{n}))$ doesn't help us somehow , right ?

Comment: A simple example is $\log(2^n) = \Theta(\log(3^n))$.

Comment: Yuval, would you be against shifting from $= \Theta$ to $\in \Theta$?

Comment: Definitely. Equals is standard notation.

Comment: Can we say that $\sqrt{n}! = \Theta(n^{1/4} (\sqrt{n})^{\sqrt{n}})$ ? I mean can we skip the factor $e$ at the denominator? Is it valid to say that $Θ((\sqrt{n}/e)^{\sqrt{n}}) = Θ((\sqrt{n})^{\sqrt{n}})$ ?

Comment: Most definitely not. It makes a huge difference.